# Sound doesn't work with MacBook Pro

Tags: audio, mac

I have a MacBook Pro and yesterday the sound just stopped working. It was funny cause I turned it off and tried and cool it down because I thought that it became too hot. After that it worked, but a few minutes later it just stopped working again.

Now there is no startup sound, there is no input and output device in System Preferences, and no, there isn't any red light. I also tried resetting PRAM and NVRAM with <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you still have warranty or AppleCare for it? Sounds like a good time to send it in.

Comment: Oh and, can you make a screen shot of your system profiler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plugging in and unplugging headphones? Sometimes the machine thinks there's a pair of headphones plugged in.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before but it's not the case. you know, today when I turned on my mac it heard The start up sound but after a while about 20 min it just stopped working again. I don't know what's the problem here. Right now in System Profiler, in audio section I haven't anything just "Audio ID: 0". I am not sure but I think this is some kind of hardware problem.

Comment: Ali, in order to regain control over your account, you have to *log in* using the same credentials as on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ali It's probably some driver like file gone bad. Try running the highest Combo installer you can find (10.6.8 for SL) that replaces a lot of files. I'm not sure about audio though, you may need a archive and install